# Does $\sin (a_n)$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given that an arbitrary $a_n > 0$, and $\sum a_n$ converges, then does $\sum \sin (a_n)$ converge also? Honestly I don't know where to start with this question. I tried some examples like $\frac{1}{n^2}$, $\frac{n^2+n}{n^4+5}$, and they all seem to follow this statement. I am beginning to think that this statement is correct. But how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to MSE ^_^

Hint:

$$\sin(x) \leq x$$

Do you see how to use this to solve your problem? Try to compare your $\sin(a_n)$ series to your original one.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Let $ x>0$.

$$t\mapsto \sin(t)\text{ is differentiable at } [0,x]$$

So, by MVT,

$$\sin(x)-\sin(0)=x\cos(c)\le x$$

---

$$a_n>0\text{ and } \sum a_n \text{ convergent}$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n=0$$

$$\implies 0<a_n<\color{red}{\pi} \text{ for large enough  } \; n$$

$$\implies 0<\sin(a_n)\le a_n$$
$$\implies \sum \sin(a_n)\text{ converges}$$
by the test of comparison.